# Workaround for writing specialization for template member function of template class when template class is not specialized

Tags: c++, templates, c++17, specialization

I'm converting existing class that has a set of template member functions specialized for in-class enumerator values into template class. However language does not allow specializations of template member functions without specialization of class template so this does not work:

```
template <typename x_Dummy>
class t_Test
{
public:
    enum t_KindId{first, second};

public:
    template <t_KindId x_kind> auto doo() -> void;
};

template <typename x_Dummy>
template<>
inline auto t_Test<x_Dummy>::doo<t_Test<x_Dummy>::t_KindId::first>() -> void
{
    return;
}
```

So I figured out I can workaround by putting template function body inside of static function of in-class partial specialization of inner template class. However this approach does not work either:

```
template <typename x_Dummy>
class t_Test
{
public:
    enum class t_KindId{first, second};

public:
    template <t_KindId x_kind> auto doo() -> void;

private:
    template <t_KindId x_kind, typename xx_Dummy = void>
    class t_DooImpl;

private:
    template <typename xx_Dummy>
    class t_DooImpl<t_KindId::first, xx_Dummy> final
    {
        friend auto t_Test<x_Dummy>::doo<t_KindId::first>() -> void;

    private:
        static inline auto doo_impl([[maybe_unused]] t_Test<x_Dummy> & self) -> void
        {
            return;
        }
    };
};

template <typename x_Dummy>
template <typename t_Test<x_Dummy>::t_KindId x_kind>
inline auto t_Test<x_Dummy>::doo(void) -> void
{
    return t_DooImpl<x_kind>::doo_impl(*this);
}

int main()
{
    using t_Test = t_Test<int>;
    t_Test t{};
    t.doo<t_Test::t_KindId::first>();
    return 0;
}
```

[clang gives](https://wandbox.org/permlink/IyejvOpuiydx84nn):

```
prog.cc:30:9: error: no candidate function template was found for dependent friend function template specialization
        doo<t_KindId::first>(void) -> void;
        ^
prog.cc:52:26: error: incomplete definition of type 't_Test<int>::t_DooImpl<t_Test<int>::t_KindId::first, void>'
        return t_DooImpl<x_kind>::doo_impl(*this);
               ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~
prog.cc:59:4: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 't_Test<int>::doo<t_Test<int>::t_KindId::first>' requested here
        t.doo<t_Test::t_KindId::first>();
          ^
2 errors generated.
```

[gcc gives](https://wandbox.org/permlink/zWPgDQBrP5k1lgXY):

```
prog.cc: In instantiation of 'class t_Test<int>::t_DooImpl<(t_Test<int>::t_KindId)0, void>':
prog.cc:52:36:   required from 'void t_Test<x_Dummy>::doo() [with t_Test<x_Dummy>::t_KindId x_kind = (t_Test<int>::t_KindId)0; x_Dummy = int]'
prog.cc:59:33:   required from here
prog.cc:29:15: error: 'doo' was not declared in this scope
   friend auto t_Test<x_Dummy>::
               ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
prog.cc:29:15: note: suggested alternative: 'bool'
   friend auto t_Test<x_Dummy>::
               ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
               bool
prog.cc: In instantiation of 'void t_Test<x_Dummy>::doo() [with t_Test<x_Dummy>::t_KindId x_kind = (t_Test<int>::t_KindId)0; x_Dummy = int]':
prog.cc:59:33:   required from here
prog.cc:52:36: error: 'static void t_Test<x_Dummy>::t_DooImpl<t_Test<x_Dummy>::t_KindId::first, xx_Dummy>::doo_impl(t_Test<x_Dummy>&) [with xx_Dummy = void; x_Dummy = int]' is private within this context
  return t_DooImpl<x_kind>::doo_impl(*this);
         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~
prog.cc:33:3: note: declared private here
   doo_impl
   ^~~~~~~~
```

vc++ gives:

```
warning C4348: 't_Test<int>::t_DooImpl': redefinition of default parameter: parameter 2
note: see declaration of 't_Test<int>::t_DooImpl'
note: see reference to class template instantiation 't_Test<int>' being compiled
error C2027: use of undefined type 't_Test<int>::t_DooImpl<t_Test<int>::t_KindId::first,void>'
note: see declaration of 't_Test<int>::t_DooImpl<t_Test<int>::t_KindId::first,void>'
note: see reference to function template instantiation 'void t_Test<int>::doo<t_Test<int>::t_KindId::first>(void)' being compiled
note: see reference to function template instantiation 'void t_Test<int>::doo<t_Test<int>::t_KindId::first>(void)' being compiled
error C3861: 'doo_impl': identifier not found
```

I'm not sure about the syntax here, but it seems that the problem is caused by friend declaration. If i make `doo_impl` function public and remove `friend` declaration it compiles fine with clang and gcc but vc still complains. So i'm looking for suggestions on how this can be fixed or maybe for a simpler workaround.

Answer (score 1):

Add a layer that you can specialize, possibly with overload for your enum:

```
template <typename T>
class t_Test
{
public:
    enum t_KindId {first, second};

public:
    template <t_KindId x_kind> void doo() { doo_impl(std::integral_constant<t_KindId , x_kind>{}); }

private:
    void doo_impl(std::integral_constant<t_KindId , first>);
    void doo_impl(std::integral_constant<t_KindId , second>);
};
```

And then:

```
template <typename T>
void t_Test<T>::doo_impl(std::integral_constant<typename t_Test<T>::t_KindId , t_Test<T>::first>)
{
    std::cout << "first" << std::endl;
}

template <typename T>
void t_Test<T>::doo_impl(std::integral_constant<typename t_Test<T>::t_KindId , t_Test<T>::second>)
{
    std::cout << "second" << std::endl;
}
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/6e95891d0b39b692)

Comment: I've managed to get this to work with vc as well by adding `#include <type_traits>` and moving `doo_impl` definition into class body.